# Расчёт дистанции до маркера и радиус поиска

Tags: google-maps, settings, marker

Всем привет,подскажите пожалуйста,храню маркеры с координатами в FireBase, как можно рассчитать дистанцию от моего местоположения до данного маркера?
А так же интересует,как сделать экран настроек,где можно ввести расстояние в КМ чтобы показывало маркеры только в установленном радиусе?Не могу понять.
[image: База данных]

Выше как выглядит база данных.

[image: Код]

Comment: Вы вручную хотите считать, или опираться на средства FireBase. С последним я не работал, но Google подсказывает, что он умеет работать с гео-данными.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko,  Ну я вывожу маркеры на карту из базы данных,и расчет можно проводить в самом приложении,вопрос только как.

Comment: `double lat = Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("latitude", ""));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("longitude", ""));
                    float[] results = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(
                            latt,longg,
                            lat, lng, results);` вот так считать дистанцию начал.Осталось радиус понять как сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double lat = Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("latitude", ""));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("longitude", ""));
                    float[] results = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(
                            latt, longg,//координаты маркера
                            lat, lng, results);//координаты юзера
                String Test = String.format("%(.2f", results[0]/1000);//делим чтобы получить км
```

В итоге сделал через такую функцию.Местоположение юзера пишу в преференс.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько методов для расчёта расстояния между точками на шаре. Один из несложных — метод гаверсинусов. Считается так:

```
public static int getDistanceInMeters(this Location source, Location destination)
{
    double φ1 = toRadians(source.latitude);
    double φ2 = toRadians(destination.latitude);
    double Δφ = toRadians(destination.latitude - source.latitude);
    double Δλ = toRadians(destination.longitude - source.longitude);

    double a = Math.sin(Δφ / 2) * Math.sin(Δφ / 2) +
               Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
               Math.sin(Δλ / 2) * Math.sin(Δλ / 2);

    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

    const double earthRadiusInMeters = 6371000;
    return (int)(earthRadiusInMeters * c);
}

private static double toRadians(double degrees)
{
    return * Math.pi / 180;
}
```

Переводил с C#, мог ошибиться. Но сама формула проверена, протестирована, работает.